# Books or/and tutorials for android programming for PHP developer

Tags: php, android

I am PHP developer and I would like to start programming simple apps for my android smart phone. Any good suggestions on tutorials or books for PHP developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever used java?

if not you'll probably need to get the basics of it down before Android. Until then [Check out sl4a](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) and their [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/TableOfContents?tm=6). That will let you bang out some basic programs as scripts much quicker and without too much work.

If you are familiar with java then check out the [commonsware books](http://commonsware.com/). For a few great tutorials and lots of good info.

Answer (score 1):

Android is coded in JAVA. So learn JAVA first.

You can use 'Busy coder's guide to Android Development' and 'Professional Android Application Development' from Wrox. These are 2 books which cover the basics of Android development.

Happy coding.